# The Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11 failed to uninstall, restarting doesn't solve fix it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, json.net, nuget

Nuget is complaining that Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11 failed to uninstall and says "Restart VS to finish the process".

After several restarts, it hasn't gone away.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete it manually from the bin folder, and from the packages file. Check also that it does not appear in your web.config

Comment: the strange this is I didn't ask to delete it either.